# "FAILED Incorrect protocol version (missing clientID/version/username)", LastFM API

Tags: http, last.fm

I'm trying to add scrobbles to my LastFM account by using their API. I managed to do the Auth and GET methods, but when trying to use the "track.scrobble" method by using this setup (The words in the curly Brackets get obviously replaced before sending the request):

**URL:** [http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.scrobble&api_key={YOUR_API_KEY}&sk={SESSION_KEY}&api_sig{API_SIGNATURE}&user={USERNAME}](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.scrobble&api_key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D&sk=%7BSESSION_KEY%7D&api_sig%7BAPI_SIGNATURE%7D&user=%7BUSERNAME%7D)

**Headers:** Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Body:** "artist=Kanye+West&timestamp={TIMESTAMP}&track=Heartless"

**Method** = POST

I get an OK Response (200), but an error from LastFm:

FAILED Incorrect protocol version (missing clientID/version/username)

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm very inexperienced working with APIs.
Any help is appreciated!!

EDIT:

The HTTP Request Itself:

```
var body = "method=track.scrobble&api_key={YOUR_API_KEY}&sk={SESSION_KEY}&api_sig{API_SIGNATURE}&artist=Daniel+Caesar&timestamp={TIMESTAMP}&track=Pseudo".format(
            {
                "YOUR_API_KEY" : APIKey,
                "SESSION_KEY" : session_key,
                "TIMESTAMP" :  str(OS.get_unix_time() - 31),
                "API_SIGNATURE" : ConstructMD5Hash()
            }
        )
    HTTP.request(
        url,
        headers,
        true,
        HTTPClient.METHOD_POST,
        body
    )
    HTTP.connect("request_completed",self,"replace_tag")
```

The ConstructMD5Hash for the API_SIGNATURE:

```
func ConstructMD5Hash() -> String:
return LastFM_MD5_Hash_Template.format(
    {
        "YOUR_API_KEY" : APIKey,
        "REQUEST_TOKEN" : request_token,
        "MY_SECRET" : APISecret,
    }
).md5_text()
```

The Full Response by LAST.FM:

> [Server: openresty/1.13.6.2, Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2023 17:10:21 GMT, Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400, Via: 1.1 google]
> FAILED Incorrect protocol version (missing clientID/version/username)

Btw I am using Godot 3.5.1, if that's of any use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Last.FM generates this error if the body lacks required parameters.

In your case the URL should be "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/" only (this is a POST method).

And the body should be:

```
"method=track.scrobble&api_key={YOUR_API_KEY}&sk={SESSION_KEY}&api_sig={API_SIGNATURE}artist=Kanye+West&timestamp={TIMESTAMP}&track=Heartless"
```

Comment: First, really appreciate the response. But even though I have applied everything you suggested I still get the same error. I have edited my code and put it up in the post, if you wanna take a look

Comment: Still wrong body. You have 
api_sig{API_SIGNATURE}
instead 
api_sig={API_SIGNATURE}